Given sides of a triangle, find the length of a given segment using elementary geometry
A triangle $_\Delta ABC$ is such that $AB=5$, $BC=3$, $AC=6$. Points $P$ on side $AB$ and $Q$ on side $BC$ are chosen in such way that $BP=BQ=2$. Find the length of $PQ$.

It can be found by applying the law of cosines twice: first to side $AC$ of the triangle $_\Delta ABC$, then to side $PQ$ of a triangle $PBQ$. However, I am looking for a way to solve it with elementary geometry.
The idea I had about that led me to this auxiliary construction: construct $BE=AB$ and then we get an isosceles triangle $ABE$, but I have no idea whether this can come in handy.



Draw height $BF$. Let $FC = y$, $9-y^2=25-(6-y)^2 \implies y=FC=\frac{5}{3}, AF=\frac{13}{3}$
From similarity, we have $HC=\frac{5}{9}$, $\frac{AG}{AF}=\frac{3}{5}, AG=\frac{13}{5}$$GH=6-\frac{13}{5}-\frac{5}{9}=\frac{128}{45}=JE$
Next, $EH=\sqrt{1-(\frac{5}{9})^2}=\frac{2\sqrt{14}}{9}$, $DG=\sqrt{9-(\frac{13}{5})^2}=\frac{2\sqrt{14}}{5}$Finally, $DE^2=x^2=(\frac{128}{45})^2+(\frac{2\sqrt{14}}{5}-\frac{2\sqrt{14}}{9})^2=\frac{128}{15}, x \approx 2.9$
